# Unable to complete purchase in revenuecat

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I am not able to complete the purchase in revenuecat...
I am able to fetch the subscriptions but I am not able to complete a transaction.

error I am getting::

```
PlatformException(2, There was a problem with the App Store., {userCancelled: false, message: There was a problem with the App Store., underlyingErrorMessage: An unknown error occurred, readableErrorCode: STORE_PROBLEM, code: 2, readable_error_code: STORE_PROBLEM}, null)
```

Main code::

```
Future<void> main() async {
   await dotenv.load();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

 
  RevenueCat.init();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "thraive-5f2ab",
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

class being used::

```
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:purchases_flutter/models/offerings_wrapper.dart';
import 'package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart';

class RevenueCat {
  static Future init() async {
    final revenueCat =
        PurchasesConfiguration(dotenv.env['REVENUE_CAT_APPLE_API_KEY']!);
    await Purchases.configure(revenueCat);
  }

  static Future<List<Offering>> fetchOfferss() async {
    print('fetchOffers()');
    try {
      final offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      final current = offerings.current;
      return current == null ? [] : [current];
    } catch (e) {
      return [];
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> purchasePackage(Package package) async {
    print('purchasePackage()');
    try {
      await Purchases.purchasePackage(package);


      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: ${e}');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

button to purchase subscription::

```
  buyFirstSubscription() async {
    print('[fetchOffers]');
    final offerings = await RevenueCat.fetchOfferss();
    if (offerings.isEmpty) {
      Utils.showSnackBar('No subscriptions!');
    } else {
      final offer = offerings.first;
      final packages = offerings
          .map((offer) => offer.availablePackages)
          .expand((pair) => pair)
          .toList();
      // print(packages);
      bool purchaseResult = await RevenueCat.purchasePackage(packages[0]);
    }
  }
```

revenuecat product::

[image: revenuecat product]

apple product:: [note that the error displaying is from when apple store reject app because my purchasing functionality was not working]

[image: apple product]

I have allowed purchases on the app::
[image: in app purchase]

when i run the app on a physical device i get the following error::

```
<SKPaymentQueue: 0x2835da000>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28398b6f0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo={NSMultipleUnderlyingErrorsKey=(
    "Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=2 \"An unknown error occurred. Please try again.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred. Please try again.}",
    "Error Domain=AMSServerErrorDomain Code=-5000 \"(null)\" UserInfo={failureType=-5000, m-allowed=false, pings=(\n), cancel-purchase-batch=true, customerMessage=The Apple\U00a0ID you entered couldn\U2019t be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again.}"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The authentication failed.}}, storefront-country-code=USA, client-environment-type=Sandbox, AMSServerErrorCode=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}
[purchases] DEBUG: ℹ️ StoreKit1Wrapper (0x00000002813c3ea0) updatedTransaction: all_features_10_1m (An unknown error occurred) 2
[error] ERROR: ‼️ There was a problem with the App Store.
[purchases] INFO:  Finishing transaction '770D6039-33FC-45E4-955B-B60C3892E409' for product 'all_features_10_1m'
[purchases] ERROR:  Product purchase for 'all_features_10_1m' failed with error: Error Domain=RevenueCat.ErrorCode Code=2 "There was a problem with the App Store." UserInfo={source_file=RevenueCat/SKError+Extensions.swift:64, readable_error_code=STORE_PROBLEM, source_function=asPurchasesError, NSLocalizedDescription=There was a problem with the App Store., NSUnderlyingError=0x28398a760 {Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x2839892c0 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28398b6f0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo=0x28229d1c0 (not displayed)}, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred}}}}}
[purchases] DEBUG: ℹ️ StoreKit1Wrapper (0x00000002813c3ea0) removedTransaction: all_features_10_1m (An unknown error occurred) ["NSLocalizedDescription": An unknown error occurred, "NSUnderlyingError": Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28398b6f0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo={NSMultipleUnderlyingErrorsKey=(
    "Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=2 \"An unknown error occurred. Please try again.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred. Please try again.}",
    "Error Domain=AMSServerErrorDomain Code=-5000 \"(null)\" UserInfo={failureType=-5000, m-allowed=false, pings=(\n), cancel-purchase-batch=true, customerMessage=The Apple\U00a0ID you entered couldn\U2019t be found or your password was incorrect. Please try again.}"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The authentication failed.}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred}] 2
flutter: error: PlatformException(2, There was a problem with the App Store., {userCancelled: false, message: There was a problem with the App Store., code: 2, underlyingErrorMessage: An unknown error occurred, readableErrorCode: STORE_PROBLEM, readable_error_code: STORE_PROBLEM}, null)
```

Comment: Was this test with an appstoreconnect sandbox account?

Comment: Is subscription status not Approved? maybe that issue try solve it

Comment: @Nirmalkumar where would I check this?

Comment: @JuanCasas got to appstoreconnect -> myapps -> app -> subscription -> select subscription -> all subscription list . there you can find the status of the subscription

see your second last screenshot

Comment: @Nirmalkumar
it says its rejected. i think that might be it.
I will ask apple what is going on

can you add me to linkedin?
I really really appreciate your help and everyone elses!!

Comment: @JuanCasas sure my LinkedIn account is https://www.linkedin.com/in/nirmalkumar-rakholiya-051456126